# Recuperar a quantia de filhos que tem um nó

Tags: android, firebase, android-adapter, firebase-database

Como faço para recuperar a quantia de filhos que tem em um nó?

Já tenho o caminho correto, só preciso saber como eu faço para contar os filhos desse nó.

```
private DatabaseReference qtdeFilRef;    
qtdeFilhosRef.child("primeiroNo").child("segundoNo");
```

Alguem sabe como fazer para recuperar os filhos do "segundoNo"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sua pergunta já foi respondida.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48645172/how-to-get-count-of-nested-nodes-of-a-parent-node-in-firebase

Testei aqui e esse código abaixo foi o que melhor me atendeu.

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference yourRef = rootRef.child("Authenticated-Users");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        int count = 0;
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            count = count + 1;
        }
        Log.d("TAG", count + "");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
yourRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: Tem outro tópico semelhante, que um membro do próprio firebase respondeu. E alertou ainda que se houver muitas consultas vai sobrecarregar a memoria e o tempo de processamento.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148803/in-firebase-is-there-a-way-to-get-the-number-of-children-of-a-node-without-load